# Fast log2(float x) implementation C++

Tags: c++, performance

I need a Very-Fast implementation of log2(float x) function in C++.

I found a very interesting implementation (and extremely fast!)

```
#include <intrin.h>

inline unsigned long log2(int x)
{
    unsigned long y;
    _BitScanReverse(&y, x);
    return y;
}
```

But this function is good only for integer values in input.

**Question:** Is there any way to convert this function to **double** type input variable?

**UPD**:

I found this implementation:

```
typedef unsigned long uint32;
typedef long int32;   
static inline int32 ilog2(float x)
{
    uint32 ix = (uint32&)x;
    uint32 exp = (ix >> 23) & 0xFF;
    int32 log2 = int32(exp) - 127;

    return log2;
}
```

which is much faster than the previous example, but the output is unsigned type.

Is it possible to make this function return a **double** type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very strange requirement, because Logarithm with base 2 is rarely used for anything except calculating number of bits for something and you work with integers when you count bits. So what do you need it for?

Comment: @JanHudec: Off the top of my head, two common uses of a logarithm would be calculating the entropy of a signal, and doing arithmetic on very large numbers that would otherwise overflow.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: For signal, it is rare to be floating point rather than integer. For arithmetic on large numbers, you wouldn't need base 2 and probably use natural logarithm as the math is usually expressed with that.

Comment: @JanHudec: Well, I'd use floating point to represent properties of a signal if that were more convenient than integer; and I might choose 2 as an arbitrary base, since that might be faster to calculate than a natural logarithm; but that's just me. There's little point arguing about it, or about whether the OP should be interested in fast logarithms.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: There is always point in asking about that. It might turn out that it would be more efficient to use something else altogether if we knew the problem or at least the problem domain.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I need to simulate a solution to differential evolution equation and it involves a lot of heavy and nested computations. The bottle neck of my calculation are time-consuming math functions like exp, log, atan. Thus, it is better for me to optimize them.

Comment: @Pomeron: Excellent, then. :)

Answer (score 10):

If you just need the integer part of the logarithm, then you can extract that directly from the floating point number.

Portably:

```
#include <cmath>

int log2_fast(double d) {
    int result;
    std::frexp(d, &result);
    return result-1;
}
```

Possibly faster, but relying on unspecified and undefined behaviour:

```
int log2_evil(double d) {
    return ((reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long&>(d) >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023;
}
```

Comment: You mean it relies on an IEEE implementation of float or double? Of course the library implementors may have also thought of that one?

Comment: @CashCow: Indeed, and it also relies on `reinterpret_cast` working as hoped - that's undefined behaviour. `frexp` certainly would take advantage of the IEEE representation; but unless the library provides it inline, that would also incur the cost of a function call, and extracting the significand. The evil version doesn't do those things.

Comment: Thank you guys! I work in the field of High-Performance Scientific Computing and thus need all basic math function to be optimized. Frankly speaking, I have 4 nested loops and the the bottle neck is some complicated math expression involving log(), exp(), atan(), sqrt(), e.t.c. I need natural logarithm function log(), but since log2() is more "popular", I can convert log2() to log() just by multiplying by log(2) (which is constant). So, my question is: how to implement the fastest possible log()/log2() function which takes double type as argument and returns also double type.

Comment: For example: log(15.37) = 2.7292

Comment: You need compiler specific commands to turn off strict alias optimizations or evil casting code is nearly guaranteed to fail.

Comment: @Pomeron You need to 1. extract the base 2 exponent like this answer does, 2. compute `log2(1.mantissa)` by approximating it with some rational function (i.e. the approximation must be valid for the interval `[1, 2)`), and 3. add the two values together. If you need precision, most time will be spent on step 2, and AFAIK, that's what the standard implementations of `log2()` do anyway. However, if you are willing to trade some precision for speed, you can just use a faster approximation of `log2()` on the interval `[1, 2)`.

Answer (score 7):

MSVC + GCC compatible version that give XX.XXXXXXX +-0.0054545

```
float mFast_Log2(float val) {
    union { float val; int32_t x; } u = { val };
    register float log_2 = (float)(((u.x >> 23) & 255) - 128);              
    u.x   &= ~(255 << 23);
    u.x   += 127 << 23;
    log_2 += ((-0.3358287811f) * u.val + 2.0f) * u.val  -0.65871759316667f; 
    return (log_2);
}
```

Comment: Slightly more accurate formula (maximum error ±0.00493976), optimized using [Remez' algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Remez.27_algorithm): `((-0.34484843f) * u.val + 2.02466578f) * u.val  - 0.67487759f`

Comment: @netvope seriously thank you for this comment, made me open my eyes, and learn approximation theory!

Comment: This is undefined behavior , you *must* use either `std::bit_cast` or `std::memcpy` if before C++20 and cross your fingers that it compiles as zero cost.   [You cannot assign a value to a union, and read it out as a different value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/is-it-allowed-to-use-unions-for-type-punning-and-if-not-why)

Answer (score 6):

*Edit:* See link by Job in the comments below for a better version.

---

[Fast log() function](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_log_Function.shtml) (5× faster approximately)

Maybe of interest for you. The code works here; It is not infinitely precise though. As the code is broken on the web page (the > have been removed) I'll post it here:

```
inline float fast_log2 (float val)
{
   int * const    exp_ptr = reinterpret_cast <int *> (&val);
   int            x = *exp_ptr;
   const int      log_2 = ((x >> 23) & 255) - 128;
   x &= ~(255 << 23);
   x += 127 << 23;
   *exp_ptr = x;

   val = ((-1.0f/3) * val + 2) * val - 2.0f/3;   // (1)

   return (val + log_2);
} 

inline float fast_log (const float &val)
{
   return (fast_log2 (val) * 0.69314718f);
}
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work. Compiled with gcc-4.4.7, fast_log2(1024.f) returns -347469.

Comment: https://github.com/romeric/fastapprox has a much faster function at the same precision, or an almost-as-fast function with much higher precision

Comment: Specifically in this header: https://github.com/romeric/fastapprox/blob/master/fastapprox/src/fastlog.h

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look into [this implementation](http://jrfonseca.blogspot.com/2008/09/fast-sse2-pow-tables-or-polynomials.html), but :

- it may not work on some platforms
- might not beat std::log

Answer (score 3):

C++11 added [std::log2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) into `<cmath>`.

Comment: Since when is anything in the standard library fast...

Answer (score 2):

This is an improvement on the first answer which does not rely on IEEE implementation, although I imagine that it is only fast on IEEE machines where `frexp()` is basically a costless function.

Instead of discarding the fraction that `frexp` returns, one can use it to linearly interpolate. The fraction value is between 0.5 and 1.0 if it is positive, so we stretch between 0.0 and 1.0 and add it to the exponent.

In practice, it looks like this fast evaluation is good to about 5-10%, always returning a value that is a little low. I'm sure it could be made better by tweaking the `2*` scaling factor.

```
#include <cmath>

double log2_fast(double d) {
    int exponent;
    double fraction = std::frexp(d, &exponent);
    return (result-1) + 2* (fraction - 0.5);
}
```

You can verify that this is reasonable fast approximation with this:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
   for(double x=0.001;x<1000;x+=0.1)
   {
      std::cout << x << " " << std::log2(x) << " " << log2_fast(x) << "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, but if you only need the integeral part of the result and don't insist on portability, there is even faster one. Because all you need is to extract the exponent part of the float!

Answer (score -2):

This function is not C++, it's MSVC++ specific. Also, I highly doubt that any such intrinsics exist. And if they did, the Standard function would simply be configured to use it. So just call the Standard-provided library.