# Two doubles with bits copied differently from a long are printed differently

Tags: c, pointers, casting, bit-manipulation, type-punning

As shown in the code below, I am trying to copy the bits from a long `longnum` to two doubles, `d1` and `d2`, using different methods: pointer-casting + dereferencing and 'bitwise-and'ing respectively.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long longnum = 0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD;
    double d1 = *((double*)(&longnum));
    double d2 = longnum & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    printf("%ld\n\n",longnum);
    printf("%lf\n\n",d1);
    printf("%lf\n",d2);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that both the doubles are not printed the same way, as shown in the output below.

```
-2459565876494606883

-1456815990147462891125136942359339382185244158826619267593931664968442323048246672764155341958241671875972237215762610409185128240974392406835200.000000

15987178197214945280.000000
```

Given the size of `DBL_MAX`, the max size of a double, it seems to me that it's the giant number that's actually the sensible output of the two doubles printed.

Comment: It's UB anyway due to the strict aliasing rule..

Comment: `long` is not required to be the same size as `double` anyway.

Comment: 1) You should use an **unsigned** fixed-width type of the correct size. **And** use `_Static_assert` to ensure `double` has that same size. It still will be implementation defined, but at least not invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double d2 = longnum & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

The `&` mask doesn't do anything. A number ANDed with all 1's is the same number. The line above is no different from:

```
double d2 = longnum;
```

That line doesn't do any bit reinterpretation. Instead it sets `d2` to the `double` that most closely represents the value in `longnum`. The value will be similar; the bit pattern will be quite different.

The best way to do what you're trying to do is with a union. Unions are the best way to perform [type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning).

```
union {
     long l;
     double d;
} u;

u.l = longnum;
printf("%f\n\n", u.d);
```

Using pointers as you did with `d1` technically invokes undefined behavior. It is a common idiom and in practice will probably work fine, but type punning with pointers ought to be avoided.

Comment: "Unions are the most direct way" - actually they are the only compliant way, if not one type is `char`.

Comment: But this type puning is illegal. Don't suggest using it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Huh? The standard explicitly allows it as one application for `union`s. Of course it is all implementation defined.

Comment: but it is not defining the result of `u.l=5; printf("%lf", u.d);` I think even not implementation specific

Comment: The union method is valid as long as `long` and `double` are the same size.

Comment: @2501 There is an intersting article [here](https://davmac.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/c99-revisited/). Also discussing some apparent exception about the trap representation in the union fields..

Comment: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.5.2.3, footnote 95: " If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
punning’’). **This might be a trap representation**."  Emphasis added.

Comment: "The line above is no different" but I am curious as to why the wrong value `15987178197214945280.000000` is printed when using the mask, but not when no mask is applied.

Comment: But using the mask `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is

```
d1 = *((double*)(&longnum));
```

by doing the above you are incorrectly taking the contents from memory and then assuming it is in double precision format.

if you do it by the following:

```
d1 = (double) longnum;
```

then the contents of the memory space longnum, which is an 8 byte integer, is **converted** properly and then **stored** properly in memory at the location pointed to by d1.
And then the contents of d1 will be correct.
suggest you read the wikipedia page about "Double-precision floating-point format"

the value of a floating point value (or double precision value)  is stored differently in memory than how integers are.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: That won't copy the bits, it'll copy the value. I believe the intention is to copy the bits.

Comment: It will do a `long`->`double` _conversion_, not just a reinterpreation of the bit-pattern. A very different thing.