# Why does the 4th output in this array become the maximum value of a short?

Tags: c++

My professor gave us this bit of code and I am confused with the output and why it happens.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[10] = { 0 };
    ((char*)&arr)[10] = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this output

```
0 0 6553600 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Where do we change the value of `arr[2]` specifically?

Comment: `((char*)&arr)[10] = 100;` modifies the eleventh byte in the array. The exact element in the array that will be affected will depend on `sizeof(int)`. If `sizeof(int) == 2`, that would be in `arr[5]`. If `sizeof(int) == 8`, that would be in `arr[1]`. In your case, it appears that `sizeof(int) == 4`, so its in `arr[3]`. Bottom line: the result you get will vary depending on implementation.

Comment: I get different and not unexpected output. https://godbolt.org/z/3neEjGrh6 `0 0 6553600 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

Comment: I get the same as @RetiredNinja here: [https://ideone.com/IRs4yP](https://ideone.com/IRs4yP)

Comment: Actually isn't that the 11th byte in the array?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: oops, yes. Thanks. I sometimes forget that normal people don't start counting from the "zeroeth" item... :-)

Comment: My concern is that if this is a C++ class, why would a professor be wasting time and energy on showing coding like this, and especially if this was given to you as homework.  C++ is tough enough as it is with "regular" coding, and showing esoteric things like this seems to be a waste of a student's learning time.

Comment: I think your professor is confused and has not caught up with C++ yet and is still teaching (type unsafe) "C" which is an endless source of bugs . Can you do me a favor and show him this [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: @JerryCoffin thank you! Can I ask what "sizeof(int)" is and how that value is determined?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Its an organization of programming languages course and for some reason we need to understand the exact value and nuance of advanced type casting or whatever this is called.

Comment: The edit by Roman seems to have completely changed the original question. I feel like it should probably be rolled back as to not put words in the asker's mouth.

Comment: @thedrooster *advanced type casting* -- Then I think you're being cheated if the class is named `C++`, when it should be simply `C`.  In C++, the usage of C++ casts should be done instead of C-style casts.

Comment: How do you determine which value in the array is being changed. Some people have said the 11th index in the array is being changed so how does that translate to the third index of the new char array and why is it that number? Wouldn't the max size of an integer with 1 byte storage be much lower?

Comment: Draw a block diagram of the original array. Put a  little space between each `int` sized unit then number each byte sized unit starting at 0. Your system probably has 4 bytes for an int.

Comment: You could also look at a memory view in your debugger and set it in byte mode to see the individual bytes of the int array.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is the number of bytes in an `int`. If you want to know it for some particular compiler, you can print it out `std::cout << sizeof(int) << '\n';` and see what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is type punning and what is the purpose of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137442/what-is-type-punning-and-what-is-the-purpose-of-it)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you retyped an `int` array to `char` array and modified it as such.

`char` size is 1 byte, `int` size is 4 bytes in your case. Modifying the 11th byte would result in modifying the 3rd `int`:

```
0 * 2^24 + 100 * 2^16 + 0 * 2^8 + 0 * 2^0 = 6553600
```

Visualization with `B` being single byte, three `int`s look like:

```
BBBB BBBB BBBB
            ^ this one you are modifying
```

On a platform with different endianess, the result would be different. Yours is little endian, it means `int` starts with the least significant byte. With big endian, the result would be 25600 instead.

On a platform with a different size of `int`, result would be also different.

Note: You usually avoid such code in most applications as it makes your code dependent on details about your platform. High level languages like C++ should shield you from such details. However you should know how things are stored in memory because sometimes, e.g. when implementing networking protocols, such code is necessary.

Comment: This sort of knowledge is rather important for implementing binary communication (file formats or network protocols)

Comment: @BenVoigt, you are right and I should know better, have fixed the note...