# Is it safe to change data via a pointer when another pointer-to-const observes it?

Tags: c, constants, compiler-optimization, pointer-aliasing

Is it a safe code, or can the compiler optimize access through `p`, such that `*p` will result in `42`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 42;
int *d = &i;

void test(int const *p) 
{
    *d = 43;
    printf("%d, %p\n", *p, (void *) p);
    printf("%d, %p\n", *d, (void *) d);
}

int main() {
    test(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I found out that `*p` is usually printed in `43`, but I wonder if there are any pitfalls here, so that in some conditions printing `*p` could yield `42`.

Comment: The variable `d` isn't pointing to constant data, you can change that as much as you want. That you have another unrelated pointer to the same data doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes but the question is more about p pointer. Is it alright to rely on p being updated or not?

Comment: Again, you have two unrelated pointers to the same data. If you use one pointer to modify the data, it should be reflected through the other pointer. The problem you mention is typical when you have actual constant data, and use pointer to non-constant data to modify the constant data. Like e.g. `int const i = 42;` and `int *d = (int *) &i;` In other words, the opposite of the code you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it a safe code, or can the compiler optimize access through p, such that *p will result in 42?

Safe.

> if there are any pitfalls here, so that in some conditions printing *p could yield 42.

No.

The compiler, if it applies such optimizations, has to be aware that you are modifying a global variable that may be aliased via another pointer and has to recompute the result at each access. `const` pointer only means that you cannot modify the memory using *that* pointer. You may consider researching `restrict` keyword and aliasing in C programming language.

Answer (score 4):

A key misunderstanding here may be how arguments are passed to functions in C. They are passed by value.

When `d` is passed to `test`, the value of the pointer (a memory address) is copied into the pointer-to-const `p`. Both contain the same memory address, but only `p`'s target is constrained by `const`.

If you try to update the data at that address by modifying `*p`, you will run into an error, but `d` is not similarly constrained, so `*d` can be used to update the data at that memory address.

Both pointers still point to the same data, so printing the int pointed to by `p` shows `43`.

Comment: You may be thinking of C++, and the leading `&` is for references.

Comment: @thebusybee: Fixed the answer to observe the difference between a "const pointer" and a "pointer to const"

Answer (score 4):

@Chris and @KamilCuk already explained why `*p` will necessarily yield `43`. But there is more to add here:

> Is it a safe code?

Your specific program is safe, but the kind of programming it demonstrates is generally not very safe.

One of these issues is **[aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing))** via pointers is somewhat error-prone: It is more likely for you to forget to account for multiple kinds of access to the same piece of data. That is not to say you should always avoid it completely, but you should strive to minimize it.

Another is the use of **global variables**: It is not automatically a bad idea, but - testability, readability, understandability, predictability of your program is usually improved by avoiding them. See the discussion in this StackOverflow question:

[Why are global variables bad, in a single threaded, non-os, embedded application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/872943/1593077)

Now, in your specific case: If you're already passing a pointer to `i` - why make `d` global? And why make `i` global in the first place?

You could, for example, write:

```
void test(int const *p)
{
    // can only use p or *p here - not d nor i
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    int *d = &i;
    test(d);
    return 0;
}
```

no globals, and the lifetime of `i` as `d` is the entire duration of the program. You just exert tighter control over who has access to what.

And a few more nitpicks:

- It's important to pick meaningful names for variables.
- When a person sees `d` and `p` as variable names, they might intuit that `p` is a pointer, but they are quite likely to assume `d` isn't. Of course they can go read the variable declaration, but sometimes it's far away and the reader won't do so.

Comment: There are no aliasing problems. He is not accessing an object using a pointer to another type (pointer punning). It is a very bad answer providing misleading, false information. He is not asking about best practices only a very specific question This "answer" definitely deserves a DV

Comment: @0___________: 1. Tried to better clarify the safety aspects are not in the specific code OP wrote. 2. Aliasing and [type punning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137442/ddg#44137664) are two separate things; I did not suggest OP's program had type punning, just aliasing.

Comment: Violation of the string aliasing rules happens when you access an object by a pointer to another type which **is** pointer punning. There are no violations of strict aliasing rules in this program

Comment: @0___________: 1. I didn't mention strings. 2. I didn't mention violation of strict aliasing, neither in general nor in this program - I was warning OP to be careful with aliasing in general. Really, I believe you're critiquing something other than my own answer...

Comment: @0___________ "aliasing" is when two pointers point to the same object.  C's "strict aliasing" rule is that this is only allowed when both pointers have the same type.  Type-based alias analysis lets a compiler prove that two pointers must not alias if they have different types, but if they have the same type, it has to respect the possibility that they do alias, unless it makes asm that checks at runtime for overlap (e.g. before a vectorized loop).  This is what einpoklum is talking about, and is using correct terminology.  You're conflating "aliasing" with "strict-aliasing violation".