# Why does std::bitset only support integral data types? Why is float not supported?

Tags: c++, std-bitset

On trying to generate the bit pattern of a float as follows:

```
std::cout << std::bitset<32>(32.5) << std::endl;
```

the compiler generates this warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long long' changes value
  from 32.5 to 32 [-Wliteral-conversion]
 std::cout << std::bitset<32>(32.5) << std::endl;
```

Output on ignoring warning :) :

```
00000000000000000000000000100000
```

Why cannot bitset detect floats and correctly output bit sequence, when casting to char* and walking memory does show correct sequence?
This works, but is machine dependent on byte ordering and mostly unreadable:

```
template <typename T>
  void printMemory(const T& data) {
    const char* begin = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&data);
    const char* end = begin + sizeof(data);
    while(begin != end)
      std::cout << std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(*begin++) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
00000000 00000000 00000010 01000010
```

Is there a reason not to support floats? Is there an alternative for floats?

Comment: Probably for the same reason it doesn't support signed integers :)

Comment: C++ does not mandate any particular bit-representation for floats.

Comment: @Dúthomhas, that's similar to byte ordering or no? At some point C++ might know how floats are represented or is it a blind passthrough?

Comment: Er, not really. C and C++ defer floating point representation to the underlying hardware (just like they do for sign representation). Granted, this is not technically any reason why std::bitset cannot accept such types as argument, but it _would_ require a technically UB cast to get the bit values of any type that isn’t a plain unsigned integer.

Comment: Oh, er, and byte order is not an issue when dealing with unsigned integers because the bits can be obtained with some simple shifts. The same cannot be said for whatever other representation may be used for other types. Some machines use different endianness for integers and floating point types, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the usual warnings about floating point formats not being standardised, endianness, etc etc

Here is code that will *probably* work, at least on x86 hardware.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

constexpr std::uint32_t float_to_bits(float in)
{
    std::uint32_t result = 0;
    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(result), "float is not 32 bits");
    constexpr auto size = sizeof(float);
    std::uint8_t buffer[size] = {};
    // note - memcpy through a byte buffer to satisfy the
    // strict aliasing rule.
    // note that this has no detrimental effect on performance
    // since memcpy is 'magic'
    std::memcpy(buffer, std::addressof(in), size);
    std::memcpy(std::addressof(result), buffer, size);
    return result;
}

constexpr std::uint64_t float_to_bits(double in)
{
    std::uint64_t result = 0;
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(result), "double is not 64 bits");
    constexpr auto size = sizeof(double);
    std::uint8_t buffer[size] = {};
    std::memcpy(buffer, std::addressof(in), size);
    std::memcpy(std::addressof(result), buffer, size);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(float_to_bits(float(32.5))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<64>(float_to_bits(32.5)) << std::endl;
}
```

example output:

```
01000010000000100000000000000000
0100000001000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Is intermediate buffer required ? a single `memcpy` should be enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 wouldn't that break the strict alias rule?

Comment: Not with `memcpy` normally, `reinterpret_cast` would (even with intermediate `char*`).

Comment: Yes, either memcpy through a char* buffer or union seem to be the only hacks possible that will not be touched by optimizers. Found this: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html

Comment: @cedoc unions are not meant for type punning, memcpy is magical and does not violate strict aliasing see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31080901/1708801)

Comment: What does everyone mean by 'memcpy is magical' ? Could someone point to where that usage comes from and what it means? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What would you expect to appear in your bitset if you supplied a float? Presumably some sort of representation of an [IEEE-7545 binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) floating point number in big-endian format? What about platforms that don't represent their `float`s in a way that's even remotely similar to that? Should the implementation bend over backwards to (probably lossily) convert the float supplied to what you want?

The reason it doesn't is that there is no standard defined format for floats. They don't even have to be 32 bits. They just usually are on most platforms.

C++ and C will run on very tiny and/or odd platforms. The standard can't count on what's 'usually the case'. There were/are C/C++ compilers for 8/16 bit 6502 systems who's sorry excuse for a native floating point format was (I think) a 6-byte entity that used [packed BCD encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

This is the same reason that `signed` integers are also unsupported. Two's complement is not universal, just almost universal. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
auto toBitset(T x) -> bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT>
{
    return bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT>{ *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long int *>(&x) };
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    while (cin >> x) {
        cout << setw(14) << x << " " << toBitset(x) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/tCz5WwHqu2X4CV1E

sadly this fails if argument type is bigger than size of `unsigned long long`, for example it will fail for `long double`. This is limit of `bitset` constructor.

Comment: Pedantically, you break strict aliasing rules with your `reinterpret_cast`.