# Raw access to union data

Tags: c

In many cases I find that I would like to have access to raw data in union but I dont want to calculate the size or I want to keep it flexible.

For example (a bit artificial, but I hope it conveys the idea), I dont want to adjust the size of raw if I change how othertype_t looks like:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef union {
  uint8_t raw[0];
  struct {
    uint8_t bar[32];
    othertype_t foo[4];
  };
} sometype_t;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Later I can do things like `sizeof(union sometype_t)` to know the size of `raw`.

Using raw[0] works but I know that is a gcc non-standard extension. How can I do this in a more portable way?

As a 'trick', I could do something like `raw[1]` but it feels a bit misleading.

*Update:*
Someone indicated that this is undefined behavior in C++. Could you include some additional information about this?

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? Because in C++, there is no portable way of type-punning with unions like that, it's undefined behavior…

Comment: If you give the structure a name you could do raw[sizeof structname] or similar.

Comment: @purpletentacle Some people think that type punning is a bad idea, and some people like to downvote questions about what they think are bad ideas.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thanks! Let's keep the discussion around C. I think it makes more sense in this context. (I updated the tags)

Comment: @SteveSummit Even if people disagree with type punning, the question is still valid. Downvoting or closing does not makes sense.

Comment: @purpletentacle I didn't say it made sense.  I usually don't agree with such downvoting.  I didn't downvote here.  You asked why someone downvoted, and I gave you my (admittedly speculative) answer.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks Steve! Yes, I understood you were trying to help.

Comment: Well, you could define an array type, [0..65535] of uint8_t, say.  You could then either unionize that in on top, (if only handling pointers so that you never have to actually allocate that much memory:), or set a pointer of that type to the same address as the struct.

Comment: I usually do this: `struct foo {...};  byte raw[BIG_ENOUGH]; do_stuff( (struct foo*)raw);`  Of course, consider required alignment.

Comment: @ddbug yes, I should have added the `pragma pack` in the question

Comment: @purpletentacle Why did you add C++ tag?

Comment: Somebody indicated that this is undefined behavior in C++. I think it is important that this is explained too. It can lead to a lot of problems.

Comment: I undid the edit, and nowhere I said it's undefined behavior. I said anonymous structures are not valid C++. They aren't part of the language, period.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is what I meant: `Because in C++, there is no portable way of type-punning with unions like that, it's undefined behavior… – Michael Kenzel `

Comment: There's no need to re-iterate that information here,  [it's already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
typedef union 
{
  struct _struct
  {
    uint8_t bar[32];
    othertype_t foo[4];
  };
  uint8_t raw[sizeof(struct _struct)];
} sometype_t;
```