# Accessing std::uint8_t as std::bitset

Tags: c++, c++11, unions, bitset

I would like to model a status register in C/C++, which should be accessible as [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/) and as [std::uint8_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). Thus I would combine them as union as follows:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

union byte {
        std::uint8_t uint;
        std::bitset<8> bitset;
};

int main(int, char*[])
{
        byte b = { .uint = 0b10101010 };

        std::cout << "Value of bit 5: "
                << (b.bitset.test(5) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Value of bit 4: "
                << (b.bitset.test(4) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Bitset Output: " << b.bitset << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Uint Output: " << static_cast<int>(b.uint) << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

This seems to work as expected, when compiled with [GCC x86_64 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/IzBdrT). However, I would like to know if I could expect this to work in all cases or if I am better off with some helper functions like `bitset`, `bittest`, ...

Comment: Type punning is undefined behavior, so you can't expect it to work. Note, that it seems to be working by pure chance (as is usually the case with UB) since std::uint8_t  and std::bitset<8> have different representations in memory (one is 1 byte and the other is 8 bytes). You can just use bitset with to_ulong method (and cast that to `uint8_t`), to avoid UB.

Comment: Type-punning using unions is allowed in C, but not in C++. I also don't think there's any requirement that the data layout of a `std::bitset` have to be directly compatible with a built-in type corresponding to the bit-size. All in all, attempting to do what you do will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @DanM. Partially wrong, the template argument for `std::bitset` is the number of *bits* not bytes.

Comment: As for your problem, if you want a type that can act as both a native `uint8_t` and handle bits in a "nice" way, then you have to implement such a class yourself. If you need it to map to a memory-mapped hardware register it should probably wrap a *pointer* to the register.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and? `bitset<N>` is not guaranteed to take exactly `N/8` bytes. See https://godbolt.org/z/oBRgT9 There is nothing wrong with my statement.

Comment: @DanM. True, but that's because the internal layout of `std::bitset` is *implementation specific*. It doesn't have to be a single byte, or a set of single bytes. It can quite literally be *anything* which is what makes the punning even worse as the types are probably not compatible in any way or form.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup. I was referring to the provided "seems to work" godbolt link. I.e. that even in such case it works purely by chance and can't be relied upon even for this specific compiler.

Comment: Thank you all, @DanM. make it an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: std::bitset<8>(std::uint8_t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do here with `union` is called type punning and is Undefined Behavior in C++ (you can read more about it [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25672839/4114447)), so it's not guaranteed to work properly even on the same compiler.

Furthermore, even if it was allowed, `std::bitset<8>` is not guaranteed to have the same representation as `std::uint8_t` (and in fact it does not on any major compiler).

In your case, you could just use the regular `std::bitset<8>` with `to_ulong` method.

Another alternative is to have a wrapper class with bitset member that would provide convenience methods to assign/convert to `uint8_t`.

Also, if you only want some limited API of `std::bitset<8>`, it might be good idea (if you want to keep the size of your class as 1 byte) to wrap around `std::uint8_t` and implement those few methods (like `test`) manually.

Answer (score 2):

I took the idea of SomeProgrammerDude's comment

> As for your problem, if you want a type that can act as both a native uint8_t and handle bits in a "nice" way, then you have to implement such a class yourself. If you need it to map to a memory-mapped hardware register it should probably wrap a pointer to the register.

and tried to make it in C++. This is the sample I came up with:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class ByteReg {
  private:
    volatile uint8_t &reg;
  public:
    explicit ByteReg(volatile uint8_t &reg): reg(reg) { }
    ByteReg(const ByteReg&) = delete;
    ByteReg operator=(const ByteReg&) = delete;
    ~ByteReg() = default;

    operator uint8_t() { return reg; }
    bool test(int i) const
    {
      assert(i >= 0 && i < 8);
      return ((reg >> i) & 1) != 0;
    }
};

int main() 
{
  volatile uint8_t hwReg = 0xaa; // 0x10101010
  ByteReg reg(hwReg);
  unsigned value = reg;
  std::cout << "reg: 0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
    << value << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    std::cout << "bit " << i << ": "
      << (reg.test(i) ? "set" : "unset") << '\n';
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
reg: 0xaa
bit 0: unset
bit 1: set
bit 2: unset
bit 3: set
bit 4: unset
bit 5: set
bit 6: unset
bit 7: set
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e81c0098562f932)</kbd>

Though, a free-standing function `testBit()` might do as well with even less code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool testBit(uint8_t reg, int i)
{
  assert(i >= 0 && i < 8);
  return ((reg >> i) & 1) != 0;
}

int main() 
{
  volatile uint8_t reg = 0xaa; // 0x10101010
  unsigned value = reg;
  std::cout << "reg: 0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
    << value << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    std::cout << "bit " << i << ": "
      << (testBit(reg, i) ? "set" : "unset") << '\n';
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/654265447149b13a)</kbd>