# How to get the stored Hex value for a given variable

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that converts a given decimal value to IEEE representation of 32-bit Hex value.
For example:
Input: `1.0`, Output: `0x3f800000`

I store the value in a variable like the following:

```
    float a = 1.0;
```

The compiler actually does the conversion of `1.0` to a Hex value. Is it possible to get the Hex value somehow from inside the C program?

Comment: Tip: Cast it to `char*` and interpret each byte (`sizeof(float)` bytes) as an 8-bit value.

Comment: The compiler doesn't convert to a hex value, it shows the internal binary representation as hex just for humans.

Comment: As @tadman suggests, declare, `char *p = (char *)&a;` then look at `*p`, `*(p+1)`, etc, for `sizeof(float)` number of bytes. You can print these as hex bytes using `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `float` and `unsigned int` are the same width, you can use the following. It is also possible to display the values byte-by-byte, as others have suggested, but then you need to account for endianness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.0f;

    //  Define an object we can easily display in hexadecimal.
    unsigned int x;

    //  Ensure our target object is the same size os float.
    _Static_assert(sizeof a == sizeof x, "Need to use another type, unsigned int is not the same width as float.");

    //  Copy the bytes representing the float into our target object.
    memcpy(&x, &a, sizeof x);

    //  Print the target object in hexadecimal.
    printf("0x%x.\n", x);
}
```

Comment: @tadman: Aliasing through a pointer is not defined by the C standard. Copying bytes, as with `memcpy`, is. Good compilers generally optimize such `memcpy` operations, so it is effectively no operation in the assembly code.

Comment: Ah, as a best-practice then, makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
float a = 1.0;
uint8_t *hexbytes = (uint8_t *)&a;
printf("0x%02X%02X%02X%02X\r\n", hexbytes[0], hexbytes[1], hexbytes[2], hexbytes[3]);
```

Comment: When I execute the code mentioned in the comments or the above answer, I see the following output: 00 00 ffffff80 3f However the expected output is 00 00 80 3f

Comment: (a) Use `unsigned char` for this, not `char`. `char` may be signed, which will cause the hex displays to have excess Fs where the `char` values are negative. (And, technically, the behavior would not be defined by the C standard.) (b) There is no need for `\r`. (c) This does not account for endianness.

Comment: Remember that results are not portable due to endianness issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions using pointer answers already here, but you could also achieve this by defining a `union` where both members are interpreting the same data as different types.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   union {
            float f;
            uint32_t u;
         } x;
   x.f=1.0;

   printf("%f %e %x\n",x.f, x.f,x.u);

}
```

*Technically this is undefined behaviour in the language standard but implemented as language extension in popular compilers. See longer answers about it here
[Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning)*

Answer (score -1):

Just check if you are missing `#include <stdint.h>`

```
#include <stdint.h> // this import is important
float a = 1.0; 
uint32_t u;
void *p;
p = &a;
u = *(uint32_t*)p;
printf("%08X\r\n", u);
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour (strict aliasing rule)

Comment: @M.M is rigth, the strict aliasing rule can be avoided using a void* pointer

Comment: using an intermediate `void *` makes no difference ; the strict aliasing rule is about the object being aliased, and the type of the expression accessing it