# Do bit fields always have the same value as union members?

Tags: c

Let's say we have the following union

```c
union {
        struct {
                unsigned a : 3;
                unsigned b : 10;
                unsigned c : 3;
        } s;
        unsigned i;
} u;
```

Can you rely on `u.i` always having the same value if `u.s` has some value `u.s = { .a = A, .b = B, .c = C }` or is this implementation defined?

Comment: You might be interested in **type punning** questions such as [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning). It has similar questions linked it the "related" panel.

Comment: You can't rely on the order of bit-fields across implementations.

Comment: Nor can you rely on the value of unspecified bits (say, if `unsigned` is bigger than 16 bits in this example).

Comment: I guess it requires `sizeof(u.s) == sizeof(unsinged)`. If `u.s` is larger the answer will likely be *no*