# Is there a std::view (or something like that) which occupies every nth element?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges

This is only a toy example, but assume I have a matrix like class

```
union {
    std::array<T, M * N> m_x;
    std::array<vector<T, M>, N> m_col;
};
```

and I want to access the `i`th row of the matrix in the sense that I can pass `begin` and `end` of this row to another function. Is there any lightweight (i.e. without introducing computational overhead) construction available for that?

Imagine for example that we want to compute a matrix-times-matrix multiplication. I would like to compute the element in the `i`th row and `j`th column (which is an inner product) by passing the `i`th row of the first and `j`th column of the second matrix to `std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)`.

I could use `boost::counting_iterator`, for example, but I would like to stick with the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [`std::views::stride`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/stride_view) in C++23, but no such counterpart exists in C++20.

```cpp
std::array<int, 9> matrix{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

for (int x : matrix | std::views::stride(3)) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5qzWGzn1j)*

This prints

```
0 3 6
```

However, this feature is quite new, and you need a recent compiler to use it at this moment.
It's also questionable how much could be gained in terms of readability by using `std::views` for matrix multiplication, but who am I to judge? ;)

In C++20 you could use the [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library to accomplish the same thing:

```cpp
#include <range/v3/view/stride.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 9> matrix{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    for (int x : matrix | ranges::views::stride(3)) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vK1fo9T86)*

#### Further notes

The `union` declaration that you have written might be a mistake. Remember that you cannot access there non-active member of a `union` outside of specific special cases.

*See also [Is it allowed to use unions for type punning, and if not, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848/5740428)*

Since this question is [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) and you may not have access to `std::views::stride(3)`, you could imitate this yourself.

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
struct matrix {
    std::array<T, N * M> data;
    
    std::span<T, 3> row(std::size_t i) {
        return {data.begin() + i * N, data.begin() + (i + 1) * N};
    }

    // TODO: similarly, return a view into a column with a column() function
    //       this function should return something like a span, except with a stride
};
```

You could then iterate over the rows and columns of a matrix by iterating over `m.row(i)` and `m.column(j)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding your further notes section: What exactly do you mean? The `vector<T, M>` class is simply a `std::array<T, M>` with some methods operating on it. Do you think there is a problem with simultaneous read and write on both `m_col` and `m_x` then?

Comment: Yes, in C++, it is undefined behavior if you access the non-active union member. You can't use `union` to "reinterpret" one object as another type, i.e. do type punning. You can only use it to share storage for two different objects that are accessed separately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *accessed separately*. I'm clearly not trying to read/write on both *concurrently* / *simultaneously*. Is it not allowed to write to `m_x` and *after that* only read from `m_col`?

Comment: Not concurrently in a multithreading sense. It would be illegal if you first wrote some data to `m_x` and then later read some data from `m_col` because `m_col` would not be the active union member. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848/5740428

Comment: On a low-level I cannot imagine why this should produce any error (assuming `T` is a POD). However, if you say it is not allowed, that is very unfortunate. Any way to achieve something similar than what my obvious intend is with the union?

Comment: You could just hide the fact that the array is multi-dimensional inside a wrapper class for the `Matrix`. Hide the ugliness away, and maybe return a `ColumnView` or `RowView` that lets you index into rows and columns. This would also let you avoid `std::views::stride` if you can't use C++23. If you can use C++23, also note that the subscript operator is multi-dimensonal, so you can write `my_matrx[i, j]`.

Comment: In essence, create a wrapper class containing a `std::array<T, N * M>`, and expose multi-dimensional features through this wrapper class.