# C++ long long int overflow/underflow

Tags: c++, c, math, overflow, underflow

I'm making a small program solving basic math operations (`*`, `/`, `+`, `-`) and I'm using `long long int` (64-bit number) so I can do math operations with big numbers.

But there is a problem. I can check the operands if they are not over or under limit (using `LONG_LONG_MAX` and `LONG_LONG_MIN`).
But when I (for example) multiply two very big numbers (which cause overflow of `long long int`) the `LONG_LONG_MAX` check doesn't work. Rather, the result is for -4.

Is there any chance in C/C++ check that? For example some try catch construction?

Comment: You can catch this by checking whether (for example) `b > MAX / a`.

Comment: Yea I wanted to do something like this but I wondered If there is a "better" way.

Comment: `long long` is at least 64 bits, but it could be more. If you want a 64 bit varibale use `int64_t`.

Comment: i do not see your problem, can you post a code example and values which do not work with it?

Comment: You could always just use a big int library and not worry about it.

Comment: By the way, in C and C++ *signed* overflow is undefined behavior, so the fact that you get `-4` in your example isn't guaranteed by the standards. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/4996248

Comment: take a look at this: [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) and study `DWORD fx32_mul(DWORD x,DWORD y)` the non asm version ... btw if you count the number of bits of mutiplication operands the result will be bounded by their sum.... so if under `64` you should be fine .... `64` is out of limit as you use signed version ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 
 x = a*b;

```
if (a != 0 && x / a != b) {
// overflow handling
}
```

refer to this post for more details

[multiplication of large numbers, how to catch overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow)