# write a logarithmic function in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, logarithm

I want to write a function to calculate the logarithm of a number to any base in c++
this function should be able to calculate the logarithm of **any numbers in any base**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int number,base;
    int i=0;//this is the counter
    double value=0; //the value of the power 
    cout<<"enter the number : "<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"enter the base : "<<endl;
    cin>>base;
    while (value<number){//if the value of the power <the number the loop will be continue 
         value=pow(base,i);
         if (value==number) //this if statment to check if the result is correct or not
         {
            break;
         }i+=1;
 }cout<<"the result is :  "<<i<<endl;//print the result on the screen

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What research have you done? Do you know how to do the calculations on paper? Start with that.

Comment: Oh, and [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Combine the existence of [`std::log`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log), with your math (log) knowledge, to get the result you want. Hint: The solution takes up 1 line.

Comment: Lastly, welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you can calculate the natural logarithm then you can calculate the logarithm in any base since : `log_a(x) = ln(x)/ln(a)`

Comment: If you can calculate the log in ANY base, then it is possible to calculate the log in any other base.    If `log_foo()` is the log in base `foo` and `log_a` is the base in base `a`, then `log_a(x) = log_foo(x)/log_foo(a)`.    And the standard library has `log()` which calculates natural logarithm as well as `log10()` which calculates common log (aka log to base `10`).  [assuming bases are positive values, not equal to 1]

Comment: see [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108287/2521214) and the links in there it might shine some light on the topic. if you can compute `log2` you can convert it to any base by simple multiplication by constant ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write the logarithm function without using the std libs,the simplest way is useing [**Binary logarithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Algorithm)

```
// function to evaluate Binary logarithm
uint16_t log2(uint32_t n) {

    if (n == 0) //throw ...
    {
        //Here we have error
        //you can use exception to handle this error or return Zero 
        throw  new exception(std::out_of_range("fault we don't have log2 0"));
    }
        uint16_t logValue = -1;
    while (n) {//
        logValue++;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return logValue;
}
```

log2 function calculate Binary logarithm in O(log n) complexity, 
and use this formula to calculate other logarithms.

> log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>c</sub> a / log<sub>c</sub> b

**And here function you want (calculate any base logarithms):**

```
// function to evaluate logarithm a base-b
uint32_t log(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return log2(a) / log2(b);
}
```

CPP main function for testing

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// driver program to test the above function
int main()
{


    uint32_t a, b;
    a = 625;
    b = 5;

    cout << "The logarithm value(base-" << b <<") of " << a
        << " is " << log(a,b) << endl;


    a = 1000;
    b = 10;

    cout << "The logarithm value(base-" << b << ") of " << a
        << " is " << log(a, b) << endl;

    a = 243;
    b = 3;

    cout << "The logarithm value(base-" << b << ") of " << a
        << " is " << log(a, b) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The logarithm value(base-5) of 625 is 4
The logarithm value(base-10) of 1000 is 3
The logarithm value(base-3) of 243 is 7
```

## **In `math.h`:**

```
Syntax for returning natural logarithm:
result = log(x)

Syntax for returning logarithm (base-10 logarithm) of the argument.
result = log10(x)
```

The parameters can be of any data-type like int, double or float or long double.

Log() function returns value according to the following conditions:

```
a) if x>1 then positive
b) if 0<x<1 returns a negative value
c) if x=1 then it returns 0
d) if x=0 then it returns -inf
e) if x<0 then it returns NaN(not a number)
```

CPP program to implement log() function

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function to evaluate natural logarithm base-e
double valueE(double d)
{
    return log(d);
}

// function to evaluate logarithm base-10
double value10(double d)
{
    return log10(d);
}

// driver program to test the above function
int main()
{
    double d = 10;
    cout << "The logarithm value(base-e) of " << d 
         << " is " << valueE(d) << endl;
    cout << "The logarithm value(base-10) of " << d 
         << " is " << value10(d) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The logarithm value(base-e) of 10 is 2.30259
The logarithm value(base-10) of 10 is 1
```

Comment: The OP wants to "make a function to calculate the logarithm of a number to **any** base" (emphasis mine). So this doesn't really help that much. And as I commented to the OP, [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: @user4581301 I update my code now. check it again

Comment: `log(0)` looks like a candidate for `std::range_error`. Throwing string literals is a bit unusual. But this is a reasonable first try. For a more serious attempt (and a StackOverflow-worthy answer) there's the matter of rounding. Your `log2` function rounds down, and your `log` uses these rounded results in an integer division which also rounds down.  In particular, `log(7*7*7, 7)` should produce 3 but calculates `8/2==4` as 256<343<512 and 4<7<8.