# Integer part of logarithm

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point, logarithm, natural-logarithm

Please, does anyone know how to compute the integer part of natural logarithm of an integer?

Preferably using integer arithmetic only (akin to [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root#Algorithm_using_Newton's_method) method), without relying on floating-point `log` (i.e. not `Math.floor(Math.log(x))`.

---

To explain why this question is not duplicate of the linked question: this deals with natural logarithm and possibly unbounded inputs, the other is for base 2 or 10 and simulates floating-point by 32-bit fixed-precision arithmetic. The other question also does not explain how many fixed bits it requires to correctly compute integer part of natural log of unbounded input.

Comment: What's your input range?

Comment: @RoryDaulton You mean as a floating-point number? If so, no, I would prefer not to.

Comment: @user3386109 Many thousands of bits, basically BigInteger range.

Comment: I think a method similar to [integer log 10](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10) can be used. But please don't cross post questions [Integer part of natural logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2894807/90333)

Comment: This is an unusual thing to do. Why are you trying to do it? There may be another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Integer part of natural logarithm comes up at few primality testing algorithm so I got curious whether there is something similar as there is for integer square roots.

Comment: A simple crude estimate is the bit length of the integer, which is available in most big int implementations, e.g. for Java it is [BigInteger.bitLength()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength--)

Comment: The most reasonable way to get a log base e with integer math is to get a log base 2 and multiply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a logarithm function in C without using float type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107700/building-a-logarithm-function-in-c-without-using-float-type)

Comment: you can use fixed point on integers... and exploit that `ln(x) = log2(x)/log2(e)` ... See the [duplicate QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107700/building-a-logarithm-function-in-c-without-using-float-type) I linked on How to compute that on integers only

Comment: @Spektre I don't believe it is duplicate, the main difference is the unbounded input.

Comment: @EcirHana What do you mean by unbound input (bigints perhaps)? the duplicate computes exactly what you are asking about. The number of fractional bits depends on precision you want as you need just integer part 8 should be more than enough. the conversion between `log2` and `ln` base is in my comment above... simple integer division by constant

Comment: I think that for `bigints` you could use the inputs bit-width for the fraction bits of the `log2(e)=1.4426950408889634073599246810019`  so after division your integer accuracy is not lost . the result after division is ~1.5 less than the input so you can use `8+(70%)` of the input bitwidth as the fraction bits count

Comment: @EcirHana: Out of curiosity, _which_ primality testing algorithms does this turn up in? (I've seen a lot of primality testing algorithms, but I don't recall ever seeing the need for floor of the natural log for them.) Do you actually need a precise value, or just an approximation, or perhaps some kind of lower or upper bound? It would be much easier to give a guaranteed and tight bound (either lower or upper) than an exact value for the floor of the natural log.

Comment: Ah, if you're assuming the truth of GRH, the Miller-Rabin test has a bound of the form `floor(2*ln(n)^2)`. Is that the sort of thing you were thinking of? In that case, a guaranteed upper bound would be plenty good enough.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes GRH, deterministic Miller's test, the one which Miller-Rabin stood from. And I understand I could add one to `Math.floor(Math.log(x))` just to be sure, I was just curios whether there is a nice way of calculating it directly with integers, as it is the case with integer square root.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that multiplication is allowed.

So you can apply [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) (a kind of binary search) approach to find such power n that

```
 e^n <= x < e^(n+1)
```

Comment: Then of course, how do I compute `e^x` using integers and what is a good initial guess for `x`?

Comment: It is impossible to compute e^x using integers only (while you don't need `Exp` function, just multiplication), Good initial guess is position of the left 1 bit in binary representation of value (binary logarithm). But what is reason for this task?

Comment: I thought by above you meant some kind of binary search for `n`. Then one would need to be able to compute `e^n`. But maybe I misunderstood..?

Comment: You are right. Binary search for n (to find `Floor(ln(x))`)

Comment: @EcirHana there are only 44 different powers of e that fits in a `uint64_t` so you can just put them into a lookup table